# How to subscribe from beginning

Tags: go, apache-kafka

I am trying to write a Kafka Consumer with GroupId `foo`, which Subscribes to a certain topic **and** reads from the very beginning (**even if there is a previous offset**). I tried to use `Subscribe` with the  rebalance callback, but it never seems to be called (have set the `go.application` setting).

Is there any example how one would make this work?

---

**EDIT**:
Added more details

Comment: which kafka library are you using?

Comment: Confluent for golang

Comment: You need to put crucial information like this in your question. Also sample code of what you have tried makes it less work for the person that might answer your question. 

For what it's worth: if you create a consumer and want to read from the beginning, why not do it with a new group.id? That will definitely cause to start the consumer from the earliest offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We now went with setting `enable.auto.commit` to `false`. This way, there will be no offset stored and we consume from the beginning on every run just fine.

Answer (score 2):

This example is from [Confluent Kafka go Github](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/blob/master/examples/consumer_example/consumer_example.go), you may only need to set the value of  `auto.offset.reset` to `kafka.OffsetBeginning.String()`:

```
package main

/**
 * Copyright 2016 Confluent Inc.
 */

// consumer_example implements a consumer using the non-channel Poll() API
// to retrieve messages and events.

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {

    broker := "YOUR_BROKER"
    group := "YOUR_GROUP"
    topics := "YOUR_TOPICS"
    sigchan := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(sigchan, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)

    c, err := kafka.NewConsumer(&kafka.ConfigMap{
        "bootstrap.servers":  broker,
        "group.id":           group,
        "session.timeout.ms": 6000,
        "auto.offset.reset":  kafka.OffsetBeginning.String()})

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Failed to create consumer: %s\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Created Consumer %v\n", c)

    err = c.SubscribeTopics(topics, nil)

    run := true

    for run == true {
        select {
        case sig := <-sigchan:
            fmt.Printf("Caught signal %v: terminating\n", sig)
            run = false
        default:
            ev := c.Poll(100)
            if ev == nil {
                continue
            }

            switch e := ev.(type) {
            case *kafka.Message:
                fmt.Printf("%% Message on %s:\n%s\n",
                    e.TopicPartition, string(e.Value))
                if e.Headers != nil {
                    fmt.Printf("%% Headers: %v\n", e.Headers)
                }
            case kafka.Error:
                // Errors should generally be considered as informational, the client will try to automatically recover
                fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "%% Error: %v\n", e)
            default:
                fmt.Printf("Ignored %v\n", e)
            }
        }
    }

    fmt.Printf("Closing consumer\n")
    c.Close()
}
```

Comment: This would only work if you changed the `group.id` for every run. Not if I want to have it fixed.

Comment: code updated. just set `YOUR_BROKER` `YOUR_GROUP` `YOUR_TOPICS`

Comment: From the code it seems you mistake what `auto.offset.reset` is for. It will only take effect the first time `YOUR_GROUP` is seen. After that, there is an offset for `YOUR_GROUP` and thus the consumer will start consuming from that offset.